# scrapy filtering duplicate requests

Tags: python, scrapy

What is the difference between the Duplicate Filter which exists in the Scheduler and the [IgnoreVisitedItems middleware](http://snipplr.com/view/67018/middleware-to-avoid-revisiting-already-visited-items/)?

Google group thread which suggests that there is a duplicate filter present in the Scheduler: http://groups.google.com/group/scrapy-users/browse_thread/thread/8e218bcc5b293532

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The duplicate filter in the scheduler only filters out the URLs already seen in a single spider run (meaning that it will get reset on subsequent runs). The IgnoreVistedItems middleware will keep a state between runs and avoiding visiting URLs seen in the past, but only for final item urls so that the rest of the site can be re-crawled (in order to find new items).

Comment: That's great. That was another question I had in mind as to how to avoid revisiting URL between runs. So this answer solves both the queries. Thanks.

Comment: Having looked at the source of the IgnoreVisitedItems middleware that is present on the snappy snippets above it seems that it does not store the visited urls in a file or permanent storage so it seems that without modifications it would actually behave the same as duplicate filter in the scheduler.

Comment: Also it is not clear as what would you call a single run and subsequent run. Does it mean stopping the scraper and running the scraper again would be subsequent runs or scraper calling a set of urls to download would be called as single run and then another set of urls to download as another run?